# How to stop appending same url parameter to post a form in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Am submitting a form and passing url parameter appending to it. for each click the parameter is appending to the same existing parameter.

This is how it is behaving, where am doing wrong. am new to backbone.

```
http://localhost:8080/abc?username=&password=?username=&password=  
http://localhost:8080/abc?username=&password=?username=&password=  
http://localhost:8080/abc?username=&password=?username=&password=?username=&password=
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" role="form" autocomplete="off" name="abc" id="abc"></form>
```

Model :

```
var signin = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults :{},
        url: '/abc'
});
```

View :

```
events: { 
    "click .sgIn" : "sigIn",
}

sigIn : function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    var data = this.$el.find('#abc').serialize();
    this.model.set(data);
    this.model.url = this.model.url+"?"+data;
    this.model.save(this.model.toJSON(), {
      success: function(model, response) {},
      error: function(model, error) {}
   });
}
```

Comment: It looks to me, that your data value is invalid or is not correctly serialized. Can you post the data object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're modifying the models `url` everytime `sigIn` is called:

```
this.model.url = this.model.url+"?"+data;
```

You can pass the url as an `xhr` option instead:

```
sigIn : function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  var data = this.$el.find('#abc').serialize();
  this.model.set(data);
  this.model.save(null, {
    url: this.model.url+"?"+data,
    success: function(model, response) {},
    error: function(model, error) {}
  });
}
```

However, sending stuff like username and password via `GET` like this is not a good idea. `save()` should be sending `POST` or `UPDATE` unless you haven't overridden something.
Also `save()` will sent the model data by default, no need to pass `this.model.toJSON()` since you're setting the data to model before calling `save()`